# Selling bitcoin for IDR

Tags: wallet, exchanges

I bought bitcoins but my currency is in Rands but I want to sell it to IDR is it possible to do so

Comment: please be a bit more specific for others to be able to answer this question, and show what you have tried before. From your question I could guess, that you have South Africa Rand, but honestly I don't know what IDR is. And: you would probably look at an exchange in both countries, so you can get in and out...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use localbitcoins and find your country/city and sell it there. Becareful when selling in person. Always meetup in a public space like starbucks, bank, or police station.